# Automated way to find out unused controllers and methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm cleaning up an old Rails application, and I managed to do quite a cleanup on the routes files.

I'm trying to figure out a way if it is possible to map the routes file with non-existent controllers and methods so I can further clean up the code.

Is this even possible?

For my specific problem this is a Rails 3 site, but the question I guess applies to all versions of Rails.

Comment: [`rake routes`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Of course, I actually use rake routes to verify the cleanup with the routes that are supposed to be in place. But if there is a way to identify controller actions not mapped to routes that would be awesome.

Comment: Is this clean up of an existing app, or are you looking to build this into your normal development work flow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to know unused routes in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913124/895789)

Comment: I have used this gem above on a test project and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: This is a cleanup of an existing app @bashford7

Comment: `rake routes` and going over your controller actions/ view links and forms with a fine toothed comb would be how I would do this. Unsure of an automated way sorry @Dynelight

Comment: @AlterLagos WOW! This seems to do the trick!
I'm going to test this a bit. Would appreciate you respond to the question with this so I can approve and you get credit!